# Where does Jonathan Edwards describe his expectations of the second coming of Jesus?

Tags: church-history, eschatology, reference-request, jonathan-edwards

In a few places I've seen claims that [Jonathan Edwards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Edwards_(theologian)) (1703–1758) believed in the imminence of Christ's return.  For example:

> [Jonathan Edwards] was convinced that the world was going to the dogs and that it was running out of time, that Jesus was going to come any minute. ([source](http://www.ligonier.org/learn/qas/are-we-living-last-days/))

And according to Bruce Shelley, Edwards thought that the US would play a significant role:

> Jonathan Edwards even preached that America would be the scene of the coming millennium! ([*Church History in Plain Language*, 359](https://books.google.com/books?id=RbfVAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA359))

I'd like to know where exactly in his writings Jonathan Edwards expresses views like these – the imminent coming of Jesus (within Edwards' lifetime?) and the location/characteristics of the millennium.